# Finding zeros in 2-variable function with constraint

Tags: matlab

I have the following VERY LONG function:

```
J = (((q*(((2*a*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/q^3 + (a^2*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/(q^(5/2)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)))/(a*q^2 + 1)^2 - ((a*q + q^(1/2))*(a^2/(q^2*(a*q^2 + 1)^2) - (2*a*(a/(q*(a*q^2 + 1)) + 1))/(q*(a*q^2 + 1))))/(q^(1/2)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1))))/2 - ((q*(((a*q + q^(1/2))^2/q^4 + (2*a*(a*q + q^(1/2))^2)/(q^(7/2)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)))/(a*q^2 + 1)^2 + ((a*q + q^(1/2))*((2*(((a/(q*(a*q^2 + 1)) + 1)*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/q^2 + (a*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/(q^3*(a*q^2 + 1))))/(a*q^2 + 1) - (2*a*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/(q^3*(a*q^2 + 1)^2)))/(q^(1/2)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1))))/3 - ((q^4 + q^2)*((2*a*(a*q^4 + q^2))/(a*q^(1/2) + 1)^2 + (((a^2*q)/(a*q^(1/2) + 1)^2 - (2*a*q^(1/2)*((a*q^(1/2))/(a*q^(1/2) + 1) - 1))/(a*q^(1/2) + 1))*(a*q^4 + q^2))/(q^2*(a*q^2 + 1)) - (a^2*(a*q^4 + q^2))/(q*(a*q^2 + 1)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)^2)))/3 + ((q + q^(1/2))*(((2*a*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/q^3 + (a^2*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/(q^(5/2)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)))/(a*q^2 + 1)^2 - ((a*q + q^(1/2))*(a^2/(q^2*(a*q^2 + 1)^2) - (2*a*(a/(q*(a*q^2 + 1)) + 1))/(q*(a*q^2 + 1))))/(q^(1/2)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1))))/3 - (((q + q^(1/2))*(((a*q + q^(1/2))^2/q^4 + (2*a*(a*q + q^(1/2))^2)/(q^(7/2)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)))/(a*q^2 + 1)^2 + ((a*q + q^(1/2))*((2*(((a/(q*(a*q^2 + 1)) + 1)*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/q^2 + (a*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/(q^3*(a*q^2 + 1))))/(a*q^2 + 1) - (2*a*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/(q^3*(a*q^2 + 1)^2)))/(q^(1/2)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1))))/4 - ((q^4 + q^2)*((2*((a*q^(1/2))/(a*q^(1/2) + 1) - 1)*(a*q^4 + q^2)^2)/(q^(5/2)*(a*q^2 + 1)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)) - (a*q^4 + q^2)^2/(q*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)^2) + (2*a*(a*q^4 + q^2)^2)/(q^2*(a*q^2 + 1)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)^2)))/4 - ((2*(a*q + q^(1/2))^3*(q + q^(1/2)))/(5*q^(9/2)*(a*q^2 + 1)^2*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)) + (2*(q^4 + q^2)*(a*q^4 + q^2)^3)/(5*q^3*(a*q^2 + 1)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)^2))/(a*q^4 + q^2) + (a*q + q^(1/2))^3/(2*q^(7/2)*(a*q^2 + 1)^2*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)))/(a*q^4 + q^2))/(a*q^4 + q^2) + ((q^4 + q^2)*((a^2*q)/(a*q^(1/2) + 1)^2 - 1))/2 + (a^2*(q + q^(1/2)))/(2*q^2*(a*q^2 + 1)^2))/(a*q^4 + q^2) - a^2/(q*(a*q^2 + 1)^2))/(a*q^4 + q^2) + (48*a*q + 24*a^2*q + 48*a*q^(1/2) - 150*a*q^3 - 45*a*q^4 + 160*a*q^5 - 20*a*q^6 - 90*a*q^(5/2) - 60*a*q^7 + 120*a*q^8 - 35*a*q^(9/2) + 2*a*q^11 - 55*a*q^12 - 60*a*q^(11/2) - 60*a*q^14 + 120*a*q^(13/2) - 60*a*q^(17/2) + 2*a*q^(21/2) + 15*a*q^(25/2) + 180*a*q^(27/2) - 15*q^2 + 24*q^(1/2) - 30*q^4 + 40*q^6 - 45*q^(5/2) - 30*q^(7/2) - 9*q^10 + 20*q^(9/2) - 10*q^12 + q^(21/2) + 30*q^(23/2) - 75*a^2*q^3 + 24*a^2*q^(3/2) - 70*a^2*q^5 - 60*a^2*q^6 - 75*a^3*q^5 + 290*a^2*q^7 + 90*a^2*q^8 + 160*a^3*q^7 - 105*a^2*q^(7/2) - 180*a^2*q^9 - 30*a^3*q^8 + 120*a^2*q^10 + 70*a^3*q^9 - 90*a^2*q^(9/2) + a^2*q^11 + 120*a^3*q^10 + 80*a^4*q^9 - 180*a^3*q^11 + 180*a^2*q^(11/2) + 10*a^2*q^13 + 40*a^3*q^12 - 90*a^4*q^11 - 150*a^2*q^14 - 105*a^3*q^(11/2) + 5*a^3*q^13 + 40*a^4*q^12 + 20*a^2*q^(13/2) - 60*a^4*q^13 - 150*a^2*q^16 + 20*a^3*q^15 - 30*a^5*q^13 - 180*a^2*q^(15/2) - 240*a^3*q^16 + 10*a^4*q^15 + 360*a^3*q^(15/2) + 260*a^2*q^(17/2) - 200*a^3*q^18 + 20*a^4*q^17 + 10*a^3*q^(17/2) - 245*a^4*q^18 + 10*a^5*q^17 + 60*a^2*q^(19/2) - 450*a^3*q^(19/2) - 150*a^4*q^20 + 10*a^5*q^19 - 240*a^2*q^(21/2) + 180*a^4*q^(19/2) - 159*a^5*q^20 + 5*a^6*q^19 + 240*a^3*q^(21/2) - 9*a^2*q^(23/2) - 60*a^5*q^22 + 2*a^6*q^21 + 240*a^3*q^(23/2) - 60*a^6*q^22 + a^7*q^21 + 10*a^2*q^(25/2) - 450*a^4*q^(23/2) - 360*a^3*q^(25/2) - 10*a^6*q^24 + 80*a^4*q^(25/2) - 10*a^7*q^24 - 45*a^3*q^(27/2) + 70*a^2*q^(29/2) + 360*a^4*q^(27/2) + 20*a^3*q^(29/2) - 150*a^5*q^(27/2) + 450*a^2*q^(31/2) - 240*a^4*q^(29/2) - 90*a^4*q^(31/2) + 160*a^3*q^(33/2) + 240*a^5*q^(31/2) + 20*a^4*q^(33/2) + 600*a^3*q^(35/2) - 60*a^5*q^(33/2) - 90*a^5*q^(35/2) + 205*a^4*q^(37/2) + 60*a^6*q^(35/2) + 10*a^5*q^(37/2) + 450*a^4*q^(39/2) - 45*a^6*q^(39/2) + 151*a^5*q^(41/2) + 2*a^6*q^(41/2) + 180*a^5*q^(43/2) - 9*a^7*q^(43/2) + 60*a^6*q^(45/2) + 30*a^6*q^(47/2) + 10*a^7*q^(49/2) + 24)/(60*q^(25/2)*(a*q^2 + 1)^7) + (a*q^(1/2)*(a^2/(q*(a*q^2 + 1)^2) - (a*q^(1/2)*((q*(((2*a*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/q^3 + (a^2*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/(q^(5/2)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)))/(a*q^2 + 1)^2 - ((a*q + q^(1/2))*(a^2/(q^2*(a*q^2 + 1)^2) - (2*a*(a/(q*(a*q^2 + 1)) + 1))/(q*(a*q^2 + 1))))/(q^(1/2)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1))))/2 + ((q^4 + q^2)*((a^2*q)/(a*q^(1/2) + 1)^2 - 1))/2 - (a*q^(1/2)*((q*(((a*q + q^(1/2))^2/q^4 + (2*a*(a*q + q^(1/2))^2)/(q^(7/2)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)))/(a*q^2 + 1)^2 + ((a*q + q^(1/2))*((2*(((a/(q*(a*q^2 + 1)) + 1)*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/q^2 + (a*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/(q^3*(a*q^2 + 1))))/(a*q^2 + 1) - (2*a*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/(q^3*(a*q^2 + 1)^2)))/(q^(1/2)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1))))/3 - ((q^4 + q^2)*((2*a*(a*q^4 + q^2))/(a*q^(1/2) + 1)^2 + (((a^2*q)/(a*q^(1/2) + 1)^2 - (2*a*q^(1/2)*((a*q^(1/2))/(a*q^(1/2) + 1) - 1))/(a*q^(1/2) + 1))*(a*q^4 + q^2))/(q^2*(a*q^2 + 1)) - (a^2*(a*q^4 + q^2))/(q*(a*q^2 + 1)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)^2)))/3 + ((q + q^(1/2))*(((2*a*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/q^3 + (a^2*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/(q^(5/2)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)))/(a*q^2 + 1)^2 - ((a*q + q^(1/2))*(a^2/(q^2*(a*q^2 + 1)^2) - (2*a*(a/(q*(a*q^2 + 1)) + 1))/(q*(a*q^2 + 1))))/(q^(1/2)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1))))/3 - (a*q^(1/2)*(((q + q^(1/2))*(((a*q + q^(1/2))^2/q^4 + (2*a*(a*q + q^(1/2))^2)/(q^(7/2)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)))/(a*q^2 + 1)^2 + ((a*q + q^(1/2))*((2*(((a/(q*(a*q^2 + 1)) + 1)*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/q^2 + (a*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/(q^3*(a*q^2 + 1))))/(a*q^2 + 1) - (2*a*(a*q + q^(1/2)))/(q^3*(a*q^2 + 1)^2)))/(q^(1/2)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1))))/4 - ((q^4 + q^2)*((2*((a*q^(1/2))/(a*q^(1/2) + 1) - 1)*(a*q^4 + q^2)^2)/(q^(5/2)*(a*q^2 + 1)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)) - (a*q^4 + q^2)^2/(q*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)^2) + (2*a*(a*q^4 + q^2)^2)/(q^2*(a*q^2 + 1)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)^2)))/4 - (a*q^(1/2)*((2*(a*q + q^(1/2))^3*(q + q^(1/2)))/(5*q^(9/2)*(a*q^2 + 1)^2*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)) + (2*(q^4 + q^2)*(a*q^4 + q^2)^3)/(5*q^3*(a*q^2 + 1)*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)^2)))/(a*q^(1/2) + 1) + (a*q + q^(1/2))^3/(2*q^(7/2)*(a*q^2 + 1)^2*(a*q^(1/2) + 1))))/(a*q^(1/2) + 1)))/(a*q^(1/2) + 1) + (a^2*(q + q^(1/2)))/(2*q^2*(a*q^2 + 1)^2)))/(a*q^(1/2) + 1)))/(a*q^(1/2) + 1) + (a^2*q^3*(q^2 + 1)*(15*a^2*q^4 - 150*a*q^(1/2) - 230*a^2*q + 80*a^3*q^3 - 20*a^4*q^2 - 130*a^3*q^(3/2) + 70*a^2*q^(5/2) + 30*a^3*q^6 + 80*a^4*q^5 + 15*a^4*q^8 + 10*a^4*q^(7/2) + 61*a^3*q^(9/2) + 10*a^5*q^(11/2) - 18*a^4*q^(13/2) - 9*a^5*q^(17/2) - 30))/(60*(a*q^(1/2) + 1)^7);
```

I am trying to find the smallest value for `a` such that `J(q,a) == 0` with the interval `q` in `[0.7, 1.0]`. I am using this for-loop:

```
quals = .7:.01:1;
qual_alpha = zeros(l,2);
counter = 0;
for q1=quals
   counter = counter + 1;
   JJ = subs(J, q, q1);
   alpha = solve(JJ==0, a);
   qual_alpha(counter, 1) = q1;
   qual_alpha(counter, 2) = alpha(1);
end
```

The result of this loop is:

```
0.700000000000000   0.183045528954296
0.710000000000000   0.162483326198972
0.720000000000000   0.145352851026052
0.730000000000000   0.131333429004711
0.740000000000000   0.120133229131580
0.750000000000000   0.111484806118576
0.760000000000000   0.105141305801803
0.770000000000000   0.100873334197590
0.780000000000000   0.098466481885027
0.790000000000000   0.097719478374352
0.800000000000000   0.098442928050464
0.810000000000000   0.100458553883238
0.820000000000000   0.103598852082798
0.830000000000000   0.107707044887249
0.840000000000000   0.112637213082333
0.850000000000000   0.118254495901928
0.860000000000000   0.124435262477302
0.870000000000000   0.131067182864133
0.880000000000000   0.138049153736913
0.890000000000000   0.145291060018183
0.900000000000000   0.152713375840150
0.910000000000000   0.160246624505360
0.920000000000000   0.167830727062574
0.930000000000000   0.175414273338365
0.940000000000000   0.182953748981668
0.950000000000000   0.190412748720123
0.960000000000000   0.197761200939535
0.970000000000000   0.204974622969659
0.980000000000000   0.212033420863554
0.990000000000000   0.218922242467939
1.000000000000000   0.225629388430389
```

From this I can guess that the smallest `a` for which `J == 0` holds must be near `q = 0.79`, because this is the smallest number in the right column.

My question is: Is there a way in MATLAB to calculate this value of `q` to perhaps 8 digits precision?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you expecting the second column to reach a value of `0`?

Comment: No, not necessarily 0, but it must be minimized, i.e., a local minimum.

Comment: you are dealing with an optimization, 'minimization' problem. there are lots of algorithms developed for different function types.

Comment: Yes I believe so. As I am new to matlab, I need some support to implement one of these types.

Comment: take a look here: http://www.mathworks.com/products/optimization/

Comment: Thanks but I believe I need some code snippet for my concrete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer may not be what you expect:

```
J(0.7, -1e8)   %//  positive
J(0.7, -1e10)  %//  negative

J(1.0, -1e8)   %// negative
J(1.0, -1e10)  %// positive
```

Further exploration shows that the function has an asymptote, and that these sign changes are probably due to numerical noise. Nevertheless, it's something to look out for.

Having said that: if you have the optimization toolbox, you can use `fmincon`:

```
function topLevel

    options = optimset(...
        'AlwaysHonorConstraints', 'bounds',...
        'TolCon', 0);
    sol = fmincon(@obj, [0.8 0.09], ...  %// objective function, initial estimate
        [],[], [],[], ...                %// no linear (in)equality constraints
        [0.7 -inf],[1.0 +inf], ...       %// one variable is bound ('q')
        @nonlcon, options)               %// the nonlinear J(q,a) == 0


    %// You want to find minimum 'a': 
    function cost = obj(x)
        cost = x(2); end

    %// the constraint: J(q,a) == 0
    function [c,ceq] = nonlcon(x)
        c = -1;

        %// NOTE: this is your function, with all 'q' replaced by x(1) 
        %// and all 'a' replaced by x(2)
        ceq = (((x(1).*(((2.*x(2).*(x(2).*x(1) + ...
    end

end
```

What I find with this:

```
sol =  %//    'q'                      'a' 
    7.898719012345190e-001    9.771935760808162e-002
```

`fmincon` stops because it exceeds the maximum function evaluations allowed. At this location:

```
>> [c,ceq] = nonlcon(sol) 
c = 
    -1
ceq =
    2.346213501258632e-016
```

so there still is *some* constraint violation (albeit too small to be able to say that this is *not* due to numerical noise).

Comment: Wow, this is of great help to me. Thanks for your detailed answer!